# Adding Futures to an immutable Seq and returning it

Tags: scala, playframework

I feel like this is not that difficult but I'm struggling with the `futures` and adding objects or `Int`s to an immutable `Seq`.

```
 def createCopyOfProcessTemplate(processTemplateId: Int): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    //val copies = Seq()

    processTemplateDTO.createCopyOfProcessTemplate(processTemplateId).flatMap { process =>
      processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplates(processTemplateId).map { steps =>
        steps.foreach(processStep =>
          copy: Future[Option[ProcessTemplateModel] = processTemplateDTO.createCopyOfStepTemplates(processTemplateId, process.get.id.get, processStep))
          //Seq should look something like this: [{processStep.id, copy.id},{processStep.id, copy.id},...] or [[processStep.id, copy.id],[processStep.id, copy.id],...]
      }

    Ok(Json.obj("copies" -> copies))
}
```

Where do I have to define the `seq` and how should I return it since it's handling `Futures` ?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please first have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html), try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Future.sequence to convert `List[Future[A]]` into `Future[List[A]]` and return as result. First, do not use `steps.foreach` with `copy` variable defined, instead use `steps.map` to get `ProcessTemplateModel` as result from `processTemplateDTO.createCopyOfStepTemplates`, and map will return List of future result - `List[Future[Option[ProcessTemplateModel]]`. Then you can convert the result with `Future.sequence` and finally return as Json object.

```
val copies:List[Future[Option[ProcessTemplateModel]] = processTemplateDTO.createCopyOfProcessTemplate(processTemplateId).flatMap { 
process =>processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplates(processTemplateId).map { steps =>
    steps.map(processStep =>
      processTemplateDTO.createCopyOfStepTemplates(processTemplateId, process.get.id.get, processStep))
}
Future.sequence(copies).map{ result =>
    Ok(Json.obj("copies" -> result))
}
```